# Error with implementing Parcelable object

Tags: android, parcelable

I'm kind of new to Android development.

I don't understand why the following code gives me a stackoverflowerror

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), MakeCall.class);
SipParcelable sipp = new SipParcelable(_sip);
intent.putExtra("sip", (Parcelable) sipp);

startActivity(intent);
```

Basically as soon as the startActivity(intent) fires, I get the following error:

[image]

I can get rid of the error by commenting out the third line with the `putExtra()` function.

I'm trying to pass my _sip object over to the MakeCall.class activity on another screen that's about to load up.  I tried to follow the tutorial on how to implement a Parcelable class/object.  Here's what my SipParcelable code looks like:

```
import com.myproject.library.SipService;
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class SipParcelable implements Parcelable{

    public SipService mData;

    /* everything below here is for implementing Parcelable */

    // 99.9% of the time you can just ignore this
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    // write your object's data to the passed-in Parcel
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel out, int flags) {
        out.writeValue(mData);
    }

    public SipParcelable(SipService sip)
    {
        mData = sip;
    }

 // Parcelling part
    public SipParcelable(Parcel in){
        mData = (SipService) in.readValue(SipService.class.getClassLoader());

    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public SipParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new SipParcelable(in); 
        }

        public SipParcelable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SipParcelable[size];
        }
    };

}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why not put the parcelable in a bundle first? you're also missing a CREATOR field in your SipParcelable class

Comment: Is the `SipService` parcelable? I.e., does it itself implement `Parcelable`?

Comment: SipService does not implement Parcelable.  I was hoping to put it into a SipParcelable class as a property.  Is that the right way to do it?  Because i'm not allowed to modify the class SipService

Comment: Not sure what putting a parcelable in a bundle means...trying to read abot it not.  I just added some extra functions , one with CREATOR, but still the same issue.

Comment: yup, the actual problem was `SipService` did not implement Parcelable. I assumed it did, sorry. Glad you got your problem figured out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SipService class must implement parcelabe and modify how SipService object is read and written from/to pracel.

check this tutorial it might help you

http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/

You can use serialisable too… But parcelable is faster and better

**NOTE: all properties of an object (if the properties are objects) that implements parcelable, must also be parcelable as well.**

Comment: But what I dont understand is why SipParcelable isn't Parcelable?  Or why my SipParcelable can't have a property that's an object?

Comment: Especially since I'm not allowed to modify SipService, so I can't make it implement parcelable....but i guess i'd have to extend it then implement it....but then back to my comment above

Comment: because you need to write how this object's attributes are written to parcel and read from it. that's why you have to implement it yourself

Comment: using parcel able is a bit frustrating since you have to implement the write and read methods.. but it is faster and made for android

Comment: Ok, so if my SipService has properties that are objects that have not implemented parcelable, and if those objects have properties that are objects that have not implemented parcelable, and if those objects have properties that are objects that have not implemented parcelable, etc.. etc.. I basically need to get the source code for all these hundreds classes and have them implement parcelable?  There's no other way around this other than to NOT use parcelable, and use serializing?

Comment: Yes,you have to do implement parcelable  for these classes. I don't recommend you use serialising, and yes sometimes I use serialising.